# Loopback Model Relation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I have a Looopback model of ***arcade.json*** and another model is ***report.json***.
Now I want to give relation in ***report.json*** which contains an array of _id of ***arcade.json***. How can I achieve this? I am using Loopback 3.x.

An array of id stored in string format but I want to stores into ObjectId (Which MongoDB stored) which as below:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5afbd860069aaa06b79f09a8"),
"name" : "Report 1",
"arcadeIDList" : [
    {
        "arcadeid" : "5ae319e8ac5718155ca719d0"
    },
    {
        "arcadeid" : "5ae31a4d770afb158ef6c048"
    }
]}
```

But I want to stores arcadeid as an ObjectId not as a string as below:

```
   {
"_id" : ObjectId("5afbd860069aaa06b79f09a8"),
"name" : "Report 1",
"arcadeIDList" : [
    {
        "arcadeid" : ObjectId("5ae319e8ac5718155ca719d0")
    },
    {
        "arcadeid" : ObjectId("5ae31a4d770afb158ef6c048")
    }
]}
```

I did it with **referencesMany** relation but I can not able store arcadeid as an ObejctId and I don't know its perfect way or not.

I read the [Github Issue #274](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/274) but I want to do it with the relation in Loopback Model.

Please do let me know If you know that how to give a relation of an array and how to define the array of _id in Loopback Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check code that helps you. I have used an array of **Ids** in my projects.

```
"userIds" : [ 
        ObjectId("5876721bc44fb9e02114d2dd"), 
        ObjectId("58767453c44fb9e02114d2e0")
    ],
```

Relation in table with **User**

```
"properties": {
"userIds" : {
          "type" : "array"
      }
  },
 "relations": {
      "users": {
          "type": "referencesMany",
          "model": "User",
          "foreignKey": "userIds"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, Man. It's working. You save a lot of time of mine. :)

Comment: i am using "referencesMany" relation. but i am getting error "Error: 5d53eaa49b826748f0b72ca5 is not an ObjectID string

Comment: In DB you should store as ObjectId("5d53eaa49b826748f0b72ca5")